# Why is architecture listed thrice in uname -a?

Tags: linux, bash, architecture

```
$ uname -a
Linux  3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Running ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. Why does it have the architecture (`x86_64`) listed thrice?

Comment: if you need arch you can use directly by : `uname -m`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I checked uname manual (man uname) and it says the following for the "-a" option:

```
 print all information, in the following order, except omit -p and -i if unknown
```

In Ubuntu, I guess, options "-m", "-p" and "-i" (machine, processor and hardware-platform) are returning the machine architecture. For example, if you use the command

```
uname -mpi
```

You will see:

```
x86_64 x86_64 x86_64
```

On the other hand, if you choose all the option:

```
uname -snrvmpio
```

You will get the same result as:

```
uname -a
```

Output:

```
Linux <hostname> 3.13.0-29-generic #53-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 4 21:00:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also executed "uname" with options "-m", "-p" and "-i" on an ARCHLINUX distro and I got a different answer:

```
x86_64 unknown unknown
```

In fact, when I asked for "uname -a" on the ARCHLINUX distro the answer was:

```
Linux <hostname> xxxxxx-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 14 20:40:47 CEST 2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

While when executed "uname -snrvmpio" on the ARCHLINUX distro I got:

```
Linux <hostname> xxxxxx-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 14 20:40:47 CEST 2015 x86_64 unknown unknown GNU/Linux
```

Comment: On SunOS:
'SunOS nsd 5.9 Generic_122300-32 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-480R'

Comment: If you need an example of a more common one where all three are different, I found some examples on google of "i686 athlon i386".